# How to get status of openshift pods without looping request every few seconds?

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-pod

is there a way I could listen to the service that is changing the status of pods that run on my openshift? I would love to store the status to my database so my web app can read the info when some customer will need it. I wouldn't mind looping through 1 pod but some of our customers can have hundreds of microservices running on openshift and looping every so often through all the pods isn't something I want to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understand your use case: why would a web app care about what pods are running? And, moreso, why would you want to store the information about which pods are running in a database? (That's what etcd and the Kubernetes API are for.)

90% of the time, unless you are building an operator, when I find people are asking these types of questions the right answer is "don't do that". Because, after all, this creates a very tight coupling to the implementation. It also means your permissions management becomes more complicated.

But with those cautionary remarks out of the way, yes, there's a pretty easy way to do what you are asking: watch operations. See the [efficient detection of changes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes) section of the API. That shows you how to receive notifications when a query (such as a query on Pods) changes.

Comment: Thank you very much that is exactly what I was looking for. And you guessed it right we are building operator and yeah there is no other option for what we need than build an operator.

Comment: That makes me feel better and understand the use case better. By it's nature, an operator is going to be tightly coupled with the implementation. I'd find it more concerning if you were trying to build this coupling as just part of general application logic.